# git push a detached head to a dev branch of remote

Tags: git

When `git push` to remote repo  of dev branch, it report

```
[detached HEAD 0091d9a] 2019-10-27 14:13:10
 1 file changed, 1 deletion(-)
fatal: You are not currently on a branch.
To push the history leading to the current (detached HEAD)
state now, use

    git push origin HEAD:<name-of-remote-branch>
```

Review the branches

```
-  (press RETURN)
* (HEAD detached from be1d973)
  develop
  master
```

Should I run

```
git push origin HEAD:develop
```

push it the current modifications to develop branch? I'm afraid of potential damage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question:

> Should I _____?

is fraught with danger regardless of what goes in the blank.<sup>1</sup>

The question as to whether you *can* do that is much simpler: yes, you can do that (`git push origin HEAD:develop`).  What that will do is call up the other Git, send them any new commit(s) needed—such as `0091d9a`—and then ask them to set *their* branch `develop` to point to this particular commit.  If *they* think it's OK for *them* to set *their* `develop`, they will do so. If they think it is not OK, they will refuse this request.  With luck, if they do refuse the request, they will also tell you *why* they think it is not OK.

If they accept, they've put the new commit(s) on their `develop`, and all the old commits that were already on their `develop` remain on their `develop`.  That's probably pretty safe, but we don't know enough about how other people are using this other Git repository, nor about your commit(s), to answer that kind of question.

---

<sup>1</sup>Should I drive a car fast (where "fast" means, say, 50 to 70 mph or about 100 km/h)?  Is that dangerous?  What if I'm in a car on a freeway, where all the other cars are also driving fast?  In that case, might it be dangerous to drive very slowly?  What if I drive at 15 mph / 25 km/h in the fast lane of the freeway?  What if I'm in a car in a parking lot or residential street?

Answer (score 1):

@torek has got you covered, but I think it's worth listing a couple of other options:

- create a branch from your HEAD: `git checkout -b name/of/branch` and then merge this into remote develop
- create a branch from your head, merge this branch into your local `develop` and push your `develop` - this seems cleaner than pushing a branch directly onto develop, this workflow will also show you any merge conflicts earlier.
- If Pull Requests are supported, then create a branch from your HEAD push this branch to the remote and create a Pull Request from this branch to `develop`.